# Using a group by or something similar using Splunk rex

Tags: splunk

If we have data like this in the splunk logs -

```
 DepId EmpName
 100    Jon
 100    Mike
 100    Tony
 200    Mary
 200    Jim
```

Is there a way to display the records with only one line for the repeating DepIds.

So for example,something like below"

```
DepId   EmpName
100     Jon
        Mike
        Tony
200     Mary
        Jim.
```

Comment: for some reason,I am not able to get the sample data above,to be displayed in tabular form

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the DepId and EmpName fields extracted, grouping them is done using the `stats` command.

```
| stats values(EmpName) as Names by DepId
```

Let us know if you need help extracting the fields.  Perhaps that's why "Splunk rex" is in the title?

Comment: Thank you for your response.I am aware of the usage of stats.But when I use it ,DepId repeats.How can I prevent repeating values,in this case DepId,from being displayed?

Comment: Please ignore.I was able to get it working by making a few changes.